# Can not ping www.google.com in Linux with new DNS

Tags: linux, networking, dns

I have a project at a hotel. With window xp, I established Static IP with hotel's DNS and I can ping and browse to google.com as well.

On Ubuntu 9.04 , I also setup with the same config as Window xp, but I can not Ping to www.google.com, however I can ping to direct address:  87.106.83.127 (ip of goole.com) .

===> I can not understand the cause , so can anybody help me ? Thanks !

p/s : one more , on linux, I can not also open Socket Connection with 87.106.83.127 although I can ping to it !

Comment: See the firewall settings.

Comment: You can turn off firewall and make a test.

Answer (score 1):

You always can choose google public DNS 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/

Btw and sorry for the offtopic that dns work really fine even for your daily usage.